# Multiline Matching in Haskell Posix

Tags: regex, haskell, functional-programming, posix, cabal

I can't seem to find decent documentation on haskell's POSIX implementation. 
Specifically the module `Text.Regex.Posix`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of using multiline matching on a string?

A snippet for the curious:

```
> extractToken body = body =~ "<textarea[^>]*id=\"wpTextbox1\"[^>]*>(.*)</textarea>" :: String
```

I'm trying to extract the source of wikipedia pages, however this method clearly falls over when more than one line is involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to `import Text.Regex.Base.RegexLike` for access to `makeRegexOpts` and friends.

```
extractToken body = match regex body where
    regex = makeRegexOpts (defaultCompOpt - compNewline) defaultExecOpt
              "<textarea[^>]*id=\"wpTextbox1\"[^>]*>(.*)</textarea>"
```

Well, since `Text.Regex.Posix`'s `defaultCompOpt = compExtended + compNewline`, that works out equivalently as

```
extractToken body = match regex body where
    regex = makeRegexOpts compExtended defaultExecOpt
              "<textarea[^>]*id=\"wpTextbox1\"[^>]*>(.*)</textarea>"
```

To pull out just the first group, use one of the other instances of [`RegexLike`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/regex-base/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t%3ARegexLike).  One possibility is

```
extractToken body = head groups where
    (preMatch, inMatch, postMatch, groups) =
        match regex body :: (String, String, String, [String])
    regex = makeRegexOpts compExtended defaultExecOpt
              "<textarea[^>]*id=\"wpTextbox1\"[^>]*>(.*)</textarea>"
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Also, is there any way to return just the match (.*), or is that only in PCRE?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use the PCRE backend instead if you want to do anything more flexible, or with better performance, than Posix regexes.

pcre-light and regex-pcre are both fine.

Comment: Would definitely be the preferred choice, however our research group has to run this on our university server, who may or may not approve the addition of new modules.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this case by matching

```
((.*)|\n*)*
```

Although this may not always work depending on your expression. 
The above solution is probably the best way to go if you're able to.