# PCRE in Haskell - what, where, how?

Tags: regex, haskell, pcre

I've been searching for some documentation or a tutorial on Haskell regular expressions for ages.  There's no useful information on the [HaskellWiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Regular_expressions). It simply gives the cryptic message:

```
Documentation
Coming soonish.
```

There is a brief [blog post](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/) which I have found fairly helpful, however it only deals with Posix regular expressions, not PCRE.

I've been working with Posix regex for a few weeks and I'm coming to the conclusion that for my task I need PCRE.

My problem is that I don't know where to start with PCRE in Haskell.  I've downloaded `regex-pcre-builtin` with cabal but I need an **example of a simple matching program** to help me get going.

- Is it possible to implement multi-line matching?
- Can I get the matches back in this format: `[(MatchOffset,MatchLength)]`?
- What other formats can I get the matches back in?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I wrote much of the wiki page and may have written "Coming soonish".  The regex-pcre package was my wrapping of PCRE using the regex-base interface, where regex-base is used as the interface for several very different regular expression engine backends.  Don Stewart's pcre-light package does not have this abstraction layer and is thus much smaller.

The blog post on Text.Regex.Posix uses my regex-posix package which is also on top of regex-base.  Thus the usage of regex-pcre will be very very similar to that blog post, except for the compile & execution options of PCRE being different.

For configuring regex-pcre the [Text.Regex.PCRE.Wrap module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-pcre/0.94.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-PCRE-Wrap.html) has the constants you need.  Use [makeRegexOptsM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t%3aRegexMaker) from regex-base to specify the options.

Answer (score 12):

There's also [regex-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) which I've written.

The idea is that you can assign some meaning to each piece of a regular expression and then compose them, just as you write parsers using Parsec.

Here's an example -- simple URL parsing.

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative

data Protocol = HTTP | FTP deriving Show

protocol :: RE Char Protocol
protocol = HTTP <$ string "http" <|> FTP <$ string "ftp"

type Host = String
type Location = String
data URL = URL Protocol Host Location deriving Show

host :: RE Char Host
host = many $ psym $ (/= '/')

url :: RE Char URL
url = URL <$> protocol <* string "://" <*> host <* sym '/' <*> many anySym

main = print $ "http://stackoverflow.com/questions" =~ url
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two main options when wanting to use PCRE-style regexes in Haskell:

- [regex-pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre) uses the same interface as described in that blog post (and also in [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html), as I think an expanded version of that blog post); this can be optionally extended with [pcre-less](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-less).  [regex-pcre-builtin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-builtin) seems to be a pre-release snapshot of this and probably shouldn't be used.
- [pcre-light](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-light) is bindings to the PCRE library.  It doesn't provide the return types you're after, just all the matchings (if any).  *However*, the [pcre-light-extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcre-light-extra) package provides a `MatchResult` class, for which you might be able to provide such an instance.  This can be enhanced using [regexqq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regexqq) which allows you to use quasi-quoting to ensure that your regex pattern type-checks; however, it doesn't work with GHC-7 (and unless someone takes over maintaining it, it won't).

So, assuming that you go with `regex-pcre`:

- According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028764/multiline-matching-in-haskell-posix) answer, yes.
- I think so, via the `MatchArray` type (it returns an array, which you can then get the list out from).
- See [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t:RegexContext) for all possible results from a regex.

Comment: I'm getting the error `Not in scope 'compNewLine'` when I try that method for multi-line matching.  I think it only works for Posix.

Comment: @NickBrunt [compMultiline](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-pcre/0.94.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-PCRE-Wrap.html#v:compMultiline) maybe then?

Comment: Isn't pcre-light-extras a contradiction?

Comment: @mcandre: yeah, I suppose the two last words kinda cancel each other out... :p

Answer (score 5):

[regexpr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regexpr) is another PCRE-ish lib that's cross-platform and quick to get started with.

Answer (score 2):

I find [rex](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rex) to be quite nice too, its ViewPatterns integration is a nice idea I think.

It can be verbose though but that's partially tied to the regex concept.

```
parseDate :: String -> LocalTime
parseDate [rex|(?{read -> year}\d+)-(?{read -> month}\d+)-
        (?{read -> day}\d+)\s(?{read -> hour}\d+):(?{read -> mins}\d+):
        (?{read -> sec}\d+)|] =
    LocalTime (fromGregorian year month day) (TimeOfDay hour mins sec)
parseDate v@_ = error $ "invalid date " ++ v
```

That said I just discovered regex-applicative mentioned in one of the other answers and it may be a better choice, could be less verbose and more idiomatic, although rex has basically zero learning curve if you know regular expressions which can be a plus.